# conditionalPanel() not working in Shiny R inside box

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

ConditionalPanel() inside box is not working. When I select 'Accession No.' from the dropdown, it should display a text input for accession number. Conversely, when I choose 'File Input' from the dropdown, it should provide a file input field. Initially, only the dropdown should be visible, and the text input or file input should appear upon selection from the dropdown.

box(
title = "RNA SEQUENCING INPUT / PARAMETER LIST",
collapsible = FALSE,
width = 6,
solidHeader = TRUE,
status = "primary",
height = "auto",
collapsed = FALSE,
header = div(
style = "background-color: darkgrey; color: white;",
"Data Upload & Parameter List"
),
fluidRow(
column(12,
box(
title = "DATA INPUT",
collapsible = TRUE,
width = 12,

```
                                          status = "primary",
                                          collapsed = TRUE,
                                               
                                          #radioButtons(
                                          selectInput(
                                       "input_type",
                                       tags$label("Select Input Type:", style = "font-weight:normal;"),
                                                 
                                       #choices = 
                                   c("Accession No." = "accession_input", "File Input" = "file_input"),
                                                 #selected = "accession_input"
                                                 
                                               ),
                                               
                                               # Use shinyjs to conditionally show/hide inputs
                                               column(6,
                                         conditionalPanel(
                                                        
                                                  condition = "input.input_type == 'accession_input'",
                                                        textInput("accession_input", "Accession No.")
                                                      )),
                                               conditionalPanel(
                                                 
                                                 condition = "input.input_type == 'file_input'",
                                                 fileInput("file_input", "Upload File")
                                               )
                                               
                                               
                                               
                                             )),
```

Comment: It works fine.  Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your issue.