# ConditionalPanel() is not working in Shiny R inside box

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

ConditionalPanel() inside box is not working. When I select 'Accession No.' from the dropdown, it should display a text input for accession number. Conversely, when I choose 'File Input' from the dropdown, it should provide a file input field. Initially, only the dropdown should be visible, and the text input or file input should appear upon selection from the dropdown.

fluidRow(
column(12,
box(
title = "DATA INPUT",
collapsible = TRUE,
width = 12,
status = "primary",
collapsed = TRUE,
#radioButtons(
selectInput(
"input_type",
tags$label("Select Input Type:", style = "font-weight:normal;"),

```
                choices = 
                c("Accession No." = "accession_input", "File Input" = "file_input"),
                                                 #selected = "accession_input"
                                                 
                                               ),
                column(6,
                conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.input_type == 'accession_input'",
                          textInput("accession_input", "Accession No.")
                                                      )),
                                    conditionalPanel(
                                                 condition = "input.input_type == 'file_input'",
                                                 fileInput("file_input", "Upload File")
                                               ))),
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to double post. [Here is your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77265039/10489562).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [conditionalPanel() not working in Shiny R inside box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77265039/conditionalpanel-not-working-in-shiny-r-inside-box)

Comment: part of your code is outside code block